# Datomic insert into database from Java

Tags: sql, insert, datomic

Having this schema notaCurs, I want to make an insert into database from java code. :notaCurs/student is a reference to another schema and :notaCurs/curs also a reference to another schema. I was able to query my database, but cound not to perform any delete, update and insert. Only select performed.

```
{:db/id #db/id[:db.part/db]
  :db/ident :notaCurs/student
  :db/valueType :db.type/ref
  :db/cardinality :db.cardinality/one
  :db/doc "Student"
  :db.install/_attribute :db.part/db}

 {:db/id #db/id[:db.part/db]
  :db/ident :notaCurs/curs
  :db/valueType :db.type/ref
  :db/cardinality :db.cardinality/one
  :db/doc "Curs"
  :db.install/_attribute :db.part/db}

 {:db/id #db/id[:db.part/db]
  :db/ident :notaCurs/nota_laboratory
  :db/valueType :db.type/bigdec
  :db/cardinality :db.cardinality/one
  :db/doc "Nota laborator"
  :db.install/_attribute :db.part/db}

 {:db/id #db/id[:db.part/db]
  :db/ident :notaCurs/nota_examen
  :db/valueType :db.type/bigdec
  :db/cardinality :db.cardinality/one
  :db/doc "Nota examen"
  :db.install/_attribute :db.part/db}

  {:db/id #db/id[:db.part/db]
  :db/ident :notaCurs/nota_final
  :db/valueType :db.type/bigdec
  :db/cardinality :db.cardinality/one
  :db/doc "Nota finala"
  :db.install/_attribute :db.part/db}
```

The insert that I am trying to perform is

```
 Long idCurs = 1223232324L;
   Long idStudent = 34335345345L;
   BigDecimal nota1 = new BigDecimal(5);
   BigDecimal nota2 = new BigDecimal(6);

List add_nota_tx = Util.list(Util.map(Util.read(":db/id"), Peer.tempid(":db.part/user") , ":notaCurs/curs", idCurs, ":notaCurs/student", idStudent, ":notaCurs/nota_examen", nota1, ":notaCurs/nota_laboratory", nota2));


        try {
            Object txResult = c.transact(add_nota_tx).get();
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

It does not print any error on stacktrace. Any help would be appreciated.

L.E. this line helped back then:

```
        db = (Database) txResult.get(Connection.DB_AFTER);
```

Comment: What went wrong exactly?  How do you know it didn't work?

Comment: I have an .edn file which contains my introduced data. And I was expecting to see my new introduced object in that file, but there is not. I have a function that I make a select to bring all my data from database again, and the new insrted line is not.

Comment: I am using a :mem database. Is there a way that my object is inserted in database, but is still in memory and i have to take it from memory and write it in my .end file?

Comment: Datomic won't write to your file (the mem db is by design non-persistent, and you should consider your edn file as a _query_ file - like a .sql file, not a data file).

Comment: Ok. Then thats why my insert is working but no data is added... But what should I do? Use another type of database, or modify the .end file after insert in order to get my new data?

Comment: I need to create 2 projects, one with SQL (and for that I am using SQLite because I do not want to have database on my computer) and the other one I need to be in Datomic (also, no database installed in my system). Is there a way to create a Datomic database as in SQLite?

Comment: I suggest you have a look at the documentation on storages for that, it's quite good.

Comment: I know is it old but... Yes, mem database do not write anything in the .edn file, in order to make CRUD operations, you must "deduct" de state of the database after the oparation. This line helped back then: db = (Database) txResult.get(Connection.DB_AFTER);